# How to use a bool to determine whether the player is jumping over

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I'm working on some animations for a game I'm working on (Still in the very early stages, and new to coding). Right now I'm trying to use a bool to detect whether or not the player is jumping, and then if it returns true, then the animation will play.

Character Controller:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Character2dController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float MovementSpeed = 8;
    public float JumpForce = 5;
    public Transform feet;

    public bool isJumping;
  
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    public LayerMask groundLayers;

   
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        isJumping = false;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Jump();
   
        //LR movement
        var movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.position += new Vector3(movement, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * MovementSpeed;
        
        isJumping = false;

    }

    //Jumping
    void Jump()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded())
        {
            isJumping = true;
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);

        }
    }

    //Grounding
    public bool IsGrounded()
    {
        Collider2D groundCheck = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(feet.position, 0.5f, groundLayers);
        
        if (groundCheck.gameObject != null)
        {
            return true; 
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

CharacterAnimation:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterAnimation : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Animator anim;
    private bool isJumping;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        isJumping = GetComponent<Character2dController>().isJumping;
        isJumping = false;
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Walking Anim
        if (Input.GetKey("a") || Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
        }

        //Character flipping
        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        }

        if(isJumping == true)
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("Up");
        }

    }

}
```

However, the isJumping bool never seems to change to true, and thus the animation will never play. I've tried putting it in a variety of places within the character controller code, but none of them seem to work. I'm wondering if there's something I'm doing wrong or if I should just use a different way to animate the player jumping.
Again I'm fairly new to coding so if there's anything that's wrong feel free to let me know. Thanks!

Comment: As a matter of approach, this is an ideal candidate for using the state machine pattern - which you can read up about here: https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html

The problem with doing it the way you've set out on is that it quickly becomes too complicated to manage - once you start trying to detect whether you've jumped or double jumped, from land or water, from standing, walking, running, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CharacterAnimation : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Animator anim;
    private bool isJumping;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        isJumping = GetComponent<Character2dController>().isJumping;//assigns value
        isJumping = false;
        
    }
.
.
.
```

The line that I commented only assigns the value of `isJumping` variable in the `Character2dController` class, to the `isJumping` variable in your `CharacterAnimation` class. Therefore when you change the `isJumping` variable in the `Character2dController` class, the `isJumping` variable in the `CharacterAnimation` class is not updated.

So instead, you could check the `isJumping` variable from the `Character2dController` class:

```
public class CharacterAnimation : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Animator anim;
    private Character2dController character2dController;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        character2dController = GetComponent<Character2dController>();//now we are holding a reference to the Character2dController component
    }
    // your other code here
    if(character2dController.isJumping == true)
    {
        anim.SetTrigger("Up");
    }
```

Also, in the `Character2dController`, you are setting `isJumping` to `false` at every frame, which is I believe not what you want to do. Instead of setting it directly to `false`, you should check whether you are grounded or not, and update the `isJumping` accordingly.

Comment: Ok thanks. Calling reference to the entire `Character2dController` makes a lot more sense than just referencing `isJumping`.
One question though. If I don't want to be constantly setting `isJumping` to `false` right within the `Update()` function, where exactly should I be updating the `isJumping` to `false` and how should I go about it? Right now I have `isJumping` setting to `true` within the `Jump()`, and an `if` statement checking whether or not `IsGrounded()` is true and updating `isJumping` to `false` that way. But it doesn't really seem to be working. I just get a lot of error messages

Comment: you are checking whether your character is on the ground or jumping in the `IsGrounded()` function. when you are on the ground, set `isJumping` to `false` before returning `true`. and you can call `IsGrounded()` in the `Update()`.

Comment: That seems to work now. I'll have to continue tweaking it a little bit but I'm happy with it for now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to get inputs with `Keycode.` like this:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
    Debug.LogError("A");
}
```

You can try to `Debug.LogError("Message on key pressed")` to be sure you are capturing the input.

If you are sure you are capturing your input properly you can indicate that in your question so that a possible helper knows that to dive deep into the code.
Also post any console error you might be getting.

Also be sure that the parameters that control the animation are set, for example in the `anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);` you are able to check in the editor itself if setting the parameter the animation takes place.